# Extract higher level combinations from input data frame of +/- combinations, BUT only allowing combinations found in the input

Tags: r, dataframe, function, data.table, combinations

I have a similar problem to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474835/r-extract-inner-higher-level-combinations-groups-of-1-2-3-and-4-elements-o), but the accepted answer does not work in this new case.

The problem is the following: I have an input data frame of +/- combinations for *n* markers (in columns), such as:

```
in_df <- data.frame(M1=c('-','+','+','-'), M2=c('-','-','+','-'), M3=c('+','-','-','-'))
```

which looks like:

```
>   in_df
  M1 M2 M3
1  -  -  +
2  +  -  -
3  +  +  -
4  -  -  -
```

These are the "lowest-level" +/- combinations of the markers. Now I need to extract the higher level combinations (groups of 1 and 2 markers, as I have 3 in total).

For that I use the accepted answer in [the question linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474835/r-extract-inner-higher-level-combinations-groups-of-1-2-3-and-4-elements-o), which is this function:

```
  nullgrid_expand_dt <- function(df, ...){
    as.data.frame(do.call(data.table::CJ, args = c(as.list(df[c(NA, seq_len(nrow(df))), ]),
                          sorted = FALSE,
                          unique = TRUE)))
  }
  #
  out_df <- nullgrid_expand_dt(in_df)
```

this produces the following output data frame with *all possible* higher-level combinations of the markers:

```
>   out_df
     M1   M2   M3
1  <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  <NA> <NA>    +
3  <NA> <NA>    -
4  <NA>    - <NA>
5  <NA>    -    +
6  <NA>    -    -
7  <NA>    + <NA>
8  <NA>    +    +
9  <NA>    +    -
10    - <NA> <NA>
11    - <NA>    +
12    - <NA>    -
13    -    - <NA>
14    -    -    +
15    -    -    -
16    -    + <NA>
17    -    +    +
18    -    +    -
19    + <NA> <NA>
20    + <NA>    +
21    + <NA>    -
22    +    - <NA>
23    +    -    +
24    +    -    -
25    +    + <NA>
26    +    +    +
27    +    +    -
```

However, my input data frame does not contain all possible "lowest-level" combinations, so the above function no longer works (in the linked question my input data frame contained all possible combination, so that function worked).

Note that my input data frame does not contain combinations `+/+/+` or `-/+/+`, for example. This means they should not be allowed in the output data frame. Similarly, combinations like `NA/+/+`, `-/+/NA`, etc should not be allowed either (since they couldn't possibly be found given the input data).

(if you checked the linked question, this is the concern brought up by @ekoam in his answer for, but back then it did not matter)

Below I'm pasting `out_df` with the rows that should not be there marked with an `X`. It would be great to account for this in the `nullgrid_expand_dt` function, in an efficient manner, extendable for any number of markers (columns).

```
>   out_df
     M1   M2   M3
1  <NA> <NA> <NA>   X
2  <NA> <NA>    +
3  <NA> <NA>    -
4  <NA>    - <NA>
5  <NA>    -    +
6  <NA>    -    -
7  <NA>    + <NA>
8  <NA>    +    +   X
9  <NA>    +    -
10    - <NA> <NA>
11    - <NA>    +
12    - <NA>    -
13    -    - <NA>
14    -    -    +
15    -    -    -
16    -    + <NA>   X
17    -    +    +   X
18    -    +    -   X
19    + <NA> <NA>
20    + <NA>    +   X
21    + <NA>    -
22    +    - <NA>
23    +    -    +   X
24    +    -    -
25    +    + <NA>
26    +    +    +   X
27    +    +    -
```

Comment: can you perhaps have a think about stating a self contained straight forward issue, as it is you seem to be relying on posting back to old threads that post back to old threads, and while it might be useful to have those resources to consider, it feels to me like I shouldnt need to read those to understand what your issue is...

Comment: I feel like the question is quite self-contained and reproducible, I only linked one previous question as context... but feel free to edit it if you think it's not clear enough

Comment: Edited for clarity, feel free to edit further

Comment: I'm afraid I dont understand the terminology `higher' and `lower` level combinations, what is mean by that. in the desired target result, what is the reason that `row 8 ; NA,+,+` is *disallowed*, `row 20 ; +,NA,+` is also *disallowed* but row `25 ; +,+,NA` is *allowed* ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm also not sure how to explain it in a better way... the intention is to find all the possible 1-marker and 2-marker combinations (which I refer to as "higher level"),  given the observed 3-marker ("lower level") ones. If your only observed combination is `m1+;m2+,m3-`, you can extract the 2-marker combination `m1+;m2+,NA`, but not `m1+;m2-,NA` (cause `m2-` is not in your set of 3-marker observed combinations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating the possible combinations row by row and then rbind'ing everything together and removing duplicates.

```
nullgrid_expand_dt <- function(df) {
  tf_list <- rep(list(c(TRUE, FALSE)), ncol(df))
  tmp     <- as.matrix(do.call(CJ, c(tf_list, unique=TRUE))[-.N])
  OUT     <- lapply(
    seq_len(nrow(in_df)),
    \(i) {
      x      <- in_df[rep(i, nrow(tmp)), ]
      x[tmp] <- NA_character_
      x
    }
  ) |> rbindlist() |> unique()
  setorderv(OUT, names(OUT))
  OUT
}
nullgrid_expand_dt(in_df)
#         M1     M2     M3
#     <char> <char> <char>
#  1:   <NA>   <NA>      +
#  2:   <NA>   <NA>      -
#  3:   <NA>      +   <NA>
#  4:   <NA>      +      -
#  5:   <NA>      -   <NA>
#  6:   <NA>      -      +
#  7:   <NA>      -      -
#  8:      +   <NA>   <NA>
#  9:      +   <NA>      -
# 10:      +      +   <NA>
# 11:      +      +      -
# 12:      +      -   <NA>
# 13:      +      -      -
# 14:      -   <NA>   <NA>
# 15:      -   <NA>      +
# 16:      -   <NA>      -
# 17:      -      -   <NA>
# 18:      -      -      +
# 19:      -      -      -
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work for the example at hand, but doesn't seem extendable to cases where number of columns isn't equal to 3...  Error `unsupported matrix index in replacement`

Comment: I think matrix `tmp` needs to be defined with the appropriate number of columns equal to the input data frame's (in `tmp <- as.matrix(CJ(tmp, tmp, tmp, unique=TRUE)[-.N])`) but so far I can't figure out how

Comment: Just added an extra answer to reflect this

Comment: I updated the function to be able to account for more (or less) than 3 columns.

Comment: @DaniCee is setorder required?

Comment: Sorry missed your comment; like this is perfect for my needs! many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just extending @s_baldur function to work with input data frames with any number of markers (in columns), not just 3 as in the question example.

```
nullgrid_expand_dt <- function(df){
  tf_list <- rep(list(c(TRUE, FALSE)), ncol(df))
  tmp <- as.matrix(do.call(data.table::CJ, args = c(tf_list, unique = TRUE))[-.N])
  out <- lapply(
    seq_len(nrow(df)),
    \(i) {
      x      <- df[rep(i, nrow(tmp)), ]
      x[tmp] <- NA_character_
      x
    }
  ) |> rbindlist() |> unique()
  setorderv(out, names(out))
  as.data.frame(out)
}
```

Example with 4 markers:

```
in_df <- data.frame(M1=c('-','+','+','-'), M2=c('-','-','+','-'), M3=c('+','-','-','-'), M4=c('+','+','+','+'))
out_df <- nullgrid_expand_dt(in_df)
```

which produces:

```
     M1   M2   M3   M4
1  <NA> <NA> <NA>    +
2  <NA> <NA>    + <NA>
3  <NA> <NA>    +    +
4  <NA> <NA>    - <NA>
5  <NA> <NA>    -    +
6  <NA>    + <NA> <NA>
7  <NA>    + <NA>    +
8  <NA>    +    - <NA>
9  <NA>    +    -    +
10 <NA>    - <NA> <NA>
11 <NA>    - <NA>    +
12 <NA>    -    + <NA>
13 <NA>    -    +    +
14 <NA>    -    - <NA>
15 <NA>    -    -    +
16    + <NA> <NA> <NA>
17    + <NA> <NA>    +
18    + <NA>    - <NA>
19    + <NA>    -    +
20    +    + <NA> <NA>
21    +    + <NA>    +
22    +    +    - <NA>
23    +    +    -    +
24    +    - <NA> <NA>
25    +    - <NA>    +
26    +    -    - <NA>
27    +    -    -    +
28    - <NA> <NA> <NA>
29    - <NA> <NA>    +
30    - <NA>    + <NA>
31    - <NA>    +    +
32    - <NA>    - <NA>
33    - <NA>    -    +
34    -    - <NA> <NA>
35    -    - <NA>    +
36    -    -    + <NA>
37    -    -    +    +
38    -    -    - <NA>
39    -    -    -    +
```